# Mech book where a dying super soldier transforms into a Japanese girl

Tags: story-identification, books, mecha

Looking for name of a book I read on my Kindle a few years ago.  It was about a retired or dying super soldier traveling to a planet. He gets attacked on a ship and when about to die a dormant program inside him transforms him into a Japanese girl and with an old friend's help takes on the mantle of head of a Japanese household.  It then deals with her new life and has Mechs as the main fighting in the book.

Comment: If it was on your kindle and it was a book you bought, it would be in your content list on Amazon.